# Start drag problem while File resize in As3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

```
coin_mc.startDrag();
coin_mc.x = stage.mouseX;
coin_mc.y = stage.mouseY;
coin_mc.mouseEnabled=false;
```

I have used the above code for drag.  It's working fine, normally . 
But when I resize the file ,the distance between mouse and coin_mc is getting increased.
So please help me regarding this  ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you made `coin_mc.stopDrag();` ?

Comment: Hi Eugency .....

       No .. Actually the problem is , I'll open my swf and will be working .
If I change that to fullscreen mode , there the problem starts ...

Comment: have you added at the begining: `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE`?

Comment: yeah Jevgenji . . Added this also but no difference .stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
a_mc.x=mouseX;
a_mc.y=mouseY;

a_mc.startDrag();

Comment: One my friend suggested this and this is working fine . 


   

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,coinMC);
function coinMC(e:Event)
{
coin_mc.startDrag();
coin_mc.x = stage.mouseX;
coin_mc.y = stage.mouseY;
coin_mc.mouseEnabled=false;
}

Comment: @Tk-Developer, so you hang something on ENTER_FRAME, so it fires up more then 20 times per second. Or I misunderstood something?

Comment: @Eugency89  .. Yeah , this only solving the problem . After scaling or giving the  fullscreen , when i move the mouse to stage , movieClip is exactly with the mousePointer

Comment: @Tk-Developer, doing something more then 20 times per second is not the best solution.